# Ionic 6 : ion-datetime opens keyboard on mobile device

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic6

I'm using the `ion-datetime` component from Ionic 6 with ionic/angular.
The time-selector is opened, a pop-over is shown with two `ion-picker-internal` to select hour and minute. You can swipe up and down to select the desired value. If the currently selected value is tapped, the number keyboard is opened, which looks very awkward and confusing.

I know there is an [issue in Ionic](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/24780) that the popover is not fully shown when at the edge of the screen. That happens when the keyboard is opened and makes the issue even worse.

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvqf0.jpg)

My goal is to have the keyboard not opened in the first place.

This is the HTML snippet where the `ion-datetime` used in my application:

```
                  <ion-datetime name="startDate"
                                [(ngModel)]="inputActivity.startDate"
                                presentation="date-time"
                                required="true"
                                class="ion-no-padding"
                                slot="content"
                  ></ion-datetime>
```

I've already studied the Ionic Datetime as well as keyboard related documentation. Setting `inputmode="none"` didn't help.

And here is a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/LAym7T5MPS1yuh1y?preview) to reproduce the issue (no Angular, just Ionic). Issue happens on iOS and Android. You might have to open the preview in a separate tab to be usable.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <ion-item button="true" id="open-date">
<ion-icon name="calendar-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
<ion-label>{{inputActivity_startDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy H:mm' }}</ion-label>
<ion-popover trigger="open-date">
  <ng-template>
    <ion-datetime
      required="true"
      class="ion-no-padding"
      presentation="time-date"
      min="1950-01-01" max="2050-01-01"
      [(ngModel)]="inputActivity_startDate"
      displayFormat="D MMM YYYY H:mm"
      show-default-buttons="true"
    ></ion-datetime>
  </ng-template>
</ion-popover>
```

and change `inputActivity.startDate` to `inputActivity_startDate` in `.ts` file

Comment: That's not exactly what I need. The `ion-datetime` has `show-default-buttons="true"` set, which additionally shows a cancel and done button; which I don't need. But the keyboard is still opened. I dug a bit more into the `ion-datetime` source and there seems to be no way to do this, other than fixing it in Ionic or re-implementing it. Thanks anyway for you effort.